# In Python 3.x and related to RSA cryptography, how to update dictionary values to boolean values?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, boolean, rsa, public-key

I'll list the requirements and a sample of my code. How to fix the code? The problem is I can't update the values of the dict. to boolean format. **It might require that I go through every value of the dict. to check for True or False**

For instance, 
Initial: D = {"1":2,"2":3}
Intended as output: D = {"1":True, "2":False}

Requirements:

- Inputs must be a Dictionary(D) and a RSA public key in the form of a tuple (e,N). **The dictionary must contains keys as messages and values as signatures.**
- Outputs must be a Dictionary with keys as messages (the same as in the input), but **with values expressed as True or False if the signature matches the public key values**.

  ```
  def Q1(D,key):
  e = key[0]
  N = key[1]

  for k,v in D.items():
      if (v ** key[0]) % key[1] == int(k) % key[1]:
          D[v] = True
      else:
          D[v] = False
  ```

It returns an error:

```
> <RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-3-9cfd98926b81> in <module>
>       9             D[v] = False
>      10 
> ---> 11 Q6({"1":2,"2":3},(5,14))
> 
> <ipython-input-3-9cfd98926b81> in Q6(D, key)
>       3     N = key[1]
>       4 
> ----> 5     for k,v in D.items():
>       6         if (v ** key[0]) % key[1] == int(k) % key[1]:
>       7             D[v] = True
> 
> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration>
```

Comment: What problem do you get with your code ?

Comment: How to change the previous values in the input to boolean values in the output? Cuz the output still needs to remain a dictionary with updated values

Comment: I know your question ^^ it’s written down there, but the problem : does your code outputs the same dictionnary without value update ?

Comment: it outputs a coding error on jupyter notebook.. that's why i think i didn't use the proper format to update dictionary values. or maybe it's better to set a D2 = { }, and then let it output a new dict with the same previous keys but with updated values as boolean

Comment: Are we supposed to guess that it throws an error ? Errors message gives you the problem, edit your post and add the message

Comment: RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-9cfd98926b81> in <module>
      9             D[v] = False
     10 
---> 11 Q6({"1":2,"2":3},(5,14))

<ipython-input-3-9cfd98926b81> in Q6(D, key)
      3     N = key[1]
      4 
----> 5     for k,v in D.items():
      6         if (v ** key[0]) % key[1] == int(k) % key[1]:
      7             D[v] = True

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: I said : edit your post please, not in comment

Comment: its updated........

Answer (score 0):

It says *dictionnary changed size* because you’re using `v` instead of `k` as index, so it adds more pair in the dictionnary and fails, change to :

```
D[k] = True
```